# Rewrite URL for path to domain in Azure App Service using Virtual Directory

Tags: azure, iis, url-rewriting, azure-web-app-service

I have set up an Azure App Service to use Virtual Directories. 
The path `my-app.azurewebsites.net/api` is working correctly with the site `wwwroot/api`.

I have a CNAME record for `api.mydomain.com` to `my-app.azurewebsites.net` which works just fine as well. I can successfully call `api.mydomain.com/api`.

However I'd like to use a subdomain instead of the path, rewriting `api.mydomain.com` to `api.mydomain.com/api`

I've added a  `web.config` file in my `wwwroot` directory which looks like following now

```
wwwroot/
- api/
- web.config
```

web.config:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
        <rule name="My redirection">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^api.mydomain.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://api.mydomain.com/api/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

After a restart, the App Service is not responsive and does not serve requests anymore. Is there a better way to achieve this or do I need to modify my rewrite?

Comment: Do you want to send a HTTP 302 redirect, or do you want the user to just to go api,mydomain.com and be able to access the API without having to redirect to api.mydomain.com/api?

Comment: the later. I just want users to host multiple sites using one app service in azure and instead of having to use a path mydomain.com/api to use a subdomain api.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

After a few attempts I figured the mistake. `Redirect` has to be changed into `Rewrite`.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
        <rule name="My redirection">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="api.mydomain.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="api/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```